# Issue with aggregate query for older/newer records

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a case where my sql is rusty, I have a table that has old and new records where I'm trying to put together an aggregate query that computes values based on subtracting sums of older values from newer ones. I'm not sure what is needed to get this working, maybe a group by?

I edited this and removed some redundancy. I'm just trying to get the difference of the row value for the columns with the sum of some column values from other records.

```
SELECT 'key',  
'NEW',  
NVL(n.MyFirstAmt,0) - SUM(NVL(o.MyFirstAmt,0)),  
NVL(n.MySecondAmt,0) - SUM(NVL(o.MySecondAmt,0)),    
SYSDATE,  
'MYUSER',  
SYSDATE,  
'MYUSER',  
o.SOME_COLUMN,  
FROM TABLE o, TABLE n  
WHERE o.id IN (1,2,3)  
AND n.id = 4
```

--GROUP BY???

Comment: I would suggest that you edit your question and provide sample data and desired resuls.

Answer (score 0):

You
Can try with analytic(over) function:

```
NVL(n.MyFirstAmt,0) - SUM(NVL(o.MyFirstAmt,0) over() )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a total shot in the dark...  I thought I understood the question until I saw the `o.SOME_NO` values in the select query -- what is your intent for these values?

On the surface, this seems like what you are trying to do, but I really am thrown for a loop as to how to hand the `SOME_NO` fields from the "old" data.

```
with old_data as (
  select
    sum (coalesce (MyFirstAmt, 0)) as MyFirstAmt,
    sum (coalesce (MySecondAmt, 0)) as MySecondAmt,
    sum (coalesce (MyThirdAmt, 0)) as MyThirdAmt,
    sum (coalesce (MyFourthAmt, 0)) as MyFourthAmt,
    sum (coalesce (MyFifthAmt, 0)) as MyFifthAmt
  from table
  where id in (4220621729,4201771785,4184084016)
)
select
  coalesce (n.MyFirstAmt, 0) - o.MyFirstAmt,
  coalesce (n.MySecondAmt, 0) - o.MySecondAmt,
  coalesce (n.MyThirdAmt, 0) - o.MyThirdAmt,
  coalesce (n.MyFourthAmt, 0) - o.MyFourthAmt,
  coalesce (n.MyFifthAmt, 0) - o.MyFifthAmt
from
  table n,
  old_data o
where
  n.id = 80002696860
```

Also, I assume the cartesian join here is intentional.  As the subquery is a single row, it doesn't seem to throw off any warning flares.